# Best electricity generation from a magical conveyor

Tags: science-based, electricity, power-sources

## The setup

I have a conveyor that is 10m long and 2m wide. The belt moves at 15,6m/s (56,16km/h).this is a magical belt that when placed, will never move from it's spot. If you remove the foundations, it'll just float there. Disregard things like Earth rotation or flying through space. If it is placed a meter from my house, it'll stay a meter from my house. It is also indestructible. The return part on the bottom of the conveyor is accessible as well, giving 10m extra to work with. There is 10cm between the conveyor top and bottom.

The conveyor is made of indestructable rubber, relatively smooth but designed so items do not slide on it.

The speed of the belt is constant. It is unable to lose or increase speed, nor can be stopped.

## Electricity generation

We have a great opportunity here to make a free energy source. Theoretically it it is infinite. If you have further indestructible materials, you can just keep increasing the size or amount of dynamos to create more and more energy. However, the world does not consist of indestructible materials [*citation needed*].

What would be the best method to generate electricity in a day? Keep in mind that breaking real world stuff during power generation is allowed, but the contraption should pay for itself. If you generate 1kW with a wheel or 2kW but use something expensive that breaks, the 1kW is preferred. Side effects not part of the contraption can be disregarded. If the surrounding countryside burns down because of heat, **this is not part of the contraption and allowed**.

The best method would:

- create the most electricity from this conveyor in any way possible.
- have the best contraption cost to energy generated in a day.
- has the best scientific explanation why this is the best method.

I've made this science based, as the details aren't 100% covering every detail, which gives some agency to the people answering the question.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151169/discussion-on-question-by-trioxidane-best-electricity-generation-from-a-magical); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 13):

Okay, I spent way too long thinking about this, trying to come up with a way to extract nuclear power or using some crazy relativistic effects, which may be possible, but I ended up going with straight mechanical force output.

Item 1 -  Friction is not an issue for the top conveyor, you can simply stack more weight on the interface for the top conveyor to increase the normal force pushing down until the infinite conveyor will move whatever you put there.  Normally this wouldn't be possible but the magic conveyor magic and will not stop, which leads to item 2.

Item 2 -  The issue with engaging the conveyor is breaking your interface, so it's a strength of materials issue.  So some rough numbers for super strong titanium alloys or high strength steel alloys puts you in the realm of 500 MPa shear strength as the max strength possible for an interfacing material.

Item 3 - How much force can the conveyor exert before exceeding this strength.  Your interface can cover 500 Mpa without breaking so over a surface area of 2m x 10m you can get a force of 10^10 Newtons of force.

Item 4 - How much power is this.  Force x velocity is power.  So... 10^10 Newtons x 15.6 m/s = 156 GW of power.

Now theoretically you could do the same for the bottom, but you would have some real issues engaging as it's not as simple as making it heavier to prevent slippage, while relying on the strength of the conveyor to hold it, but I'm going for a theoretical maximum here so assume it works and you get twice as much by using the top and bottom surfaces.  So you're looking at max power out as 312 GW.

Now you asked for electric power.  Mechanical to electrical conversion can be pretty efficient, the highest conversion efficiencies get up to around 98%.  So I'm going with around 306 GW of electrical output.  We're going to ignore how you dissipate the 6 GW of waste heat from conversion inefficiency as well as many other practical limitations which would likely lead to you getting much less, but if you want the max theoretically possible: 306 GW

Comment: Excellent [Fermi approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem). Upvoted. To put those 300 GW in perspective, the average total electric power production of the USA is about 480 GW, so this magical device could satisfy maybe about 2/3 of the electric power needs of the USA.

Comment: 16m/s is peanuts. Strap your arbitrarily efficient arbitrarily constructed arbitrarily large mechanical to electrical converter to the moon and crash the immovable object comoving with the surface of the Earth into the moon at $30km/s$...

Comment: Also for some random references 10^10 Newtons of force is equivalent to the force from a weight of about 1 million tons (the great pyramid at giza weighs about 6 million tons) and 6 GW of waste heat would boil about 5000 gallons of water per second.

Comment: "Newtons of force" is redundant. Newtons _are_ a unit of force, by themselves.

Comment: Perhaps the belt to metal contact could be the end or middle of a large-diameter shaft which rests much of its weight on the belt.  (If it wasn't perfectly immobile, perhaps pressing the belt into another roller below.  Or with springs and bearings pulling the bottom roller up and the top roller down.)  So you can have gears cut into the solid steel shaft at multiple points along its length, with each gear extracting mechanical work and stepping up the rotation speed with a gearbox to drive a generator.  Build a desalination plant to use the waste heat to boil water.

Comment: Hrm, but a round shaft would only touch the rubber belt over a limited contact patch, not the full area which we were counting on.  Perhaps a segmented metal belt or chain?  But that seems much harder to make strong enough.  If the rubber is stretchy so we can put the shaft *between* the top and bottom of the belt, much of it will be touching a round metal shaft so we can hope to get within an order of magnitude of the total force.

Comment: Turned those comments [into an answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253914/best-electricity-generation-from-a-magical-conveyor/253958#253958)

Comment: does the higher material strength offset the much lower coefficient of friction?

Comment: I don't believe you can extract anything like that energy from below because you're limited to how hard you can push up against it and that's limited by the materials of whatever's doing the pushing.

Answer (score 6):

The limiting factor on your magical conveyor belt is that it will always move at precisely the same speed. On the other hand, the thing that makes the conveyor potentially great is that it will *always* move at *precisely* the same speed. No matter how much load you add, it will keep trundling along.

In theory, you could make great use of this. Simply press an axle (small wheel on the contact surface optional) against the belt and hook the other end up to a humongous gear, which in turn drives a much smaller gear connected to the driveshaft of a large dynamo (think the ones in hydroelectric dams or nuclear power stations).

In practice, however, this is not workable. As you pointed out in your question, while the conveyor belt can take infinite load, the materials of the gears cannot. There is another problem too, although less obvious: *friction*.

As you describe it, the magic conveyor belt does not have any convenient points to mount a gear. Therefore, in order to extract energy from it, you have to use a wheel pressed against its surface (as I described earlier). Even if the belt surface has infinite friction, whatever material you use for the contact surface does not. Once you put enough load on it, the contact surface will begin to slip or erode* away.

While the conveyor has (theoretically) infinite energy, the amount of actual *usefulness* you can get from it is pretty limited. At best, I imagine that you could power a neighborhood using the setup I described above.

<sup>* This brings us back to what I mentioned about the load limits of gears. In the end, a gear is just a way of artificially increasing the friction between two wheels so that the limiting factor becomes erosion (teeth snapping) instead of slipping.</sup>

Comment: Instead of wheels, what about a track that touches the most surface area (even down the edges) of the conveyor? This track would then on the other end connect and pull any amount of gears you want. Which means the limit would likely be the material strength of the track as it’s constantly pulled against the friction of the gears and dynamo’s it powers. That would vastly increase the power output, especially when you dig a hole and do the same on the underside

Comment: I agree with Demigan. 10mx2mx2sides = 40m^2 of rubber to rubber friction could be a real step-up from a few gears. Also: since currently the limiting factor is the strength of the track, one could divide the 10meter magic track to contact with 4x2,5m real (rubber) track

Answer (score 4):

First idea: make heat from friction.  Cover the belt with a *deep* layer of sand or gravel (or other material?) whose weight pushes it down onto the belt.  Friction creates huge amounts of heat as it drags sand through sand and grinds it to dust, and friction between the belt and any material touching it. Immerse in water (or other working fluid) which boils, driving steam turbines.  We're not limited by materials strength, we just keep feeding gravel into the crusher.  But this relies on consistent forces pushing gravel into the belt, no jams in the gravel.

The water could be salt water, doubling as a desalination plant (unless too much salt ends up in the air/vapor and corrodes the turbines), or ore smelter if we omit the water.  The belt is presumably indestructible by heat as well as mechanical puncturing / scraping / cutting.

---

**Or extract mechanical work directly to turn generators**.  Building on the ideas of others, especially [Josh King's](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253914/best-electricity-generation-from-a-magical-conveyor/253926#253926) upper bound on force from materials strength limits.  And the OP's invitation to take liberties with the details of the belt (letting it deform to fit around a shaft).

This could semi-plausibly extract a significant fraction of Josh's theoretical max power, given material strength limits.  Like within an order of magnitude of that 306 GW, so perhaps 30 GW.  (The world's largest real power plant is the [Three Gorges Dam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Gorges_Dam), generating 22.5 GW from 32x 700 MW turbines.)

**A large-diameter round metal shaft** seems like the best bet to extract work from the belt.  Along the length of the shaft, to either side of the belt, cut gears into it so multiple gearboxes can extract reasonable amounts of power, with each one being far from the strength limits of steel so it's possible to build bearings and smaller gears that turn faster.

This also spreads out the waste-heat, although if there's a lot right around the shaft, perhaps capture that for district-level heating and/or boiling water for desalination and/or steam turbines.  But we can't let the steel or titanium shaft get red hot, that would weaken it.  Fortunately metal conducts heat quite well, and portions with a stainless steel coating could have water poured over it for cooling.

The shaft is *heavy* and much of its weight is supported by the belt, for large contact friction forces.  Far to either side of the belt, there are bearings that keep it stable and gears that it rests on to transfer power into.  (I'm picturing the shaft would flex from having its weight supported mostly at the middle, so the metal is constantly bending in different directions as it rotates (tension at the top, compression at the bottom).  This might not be viable for a huge driveshaft.  So heavy rollers might be necessary to apply force at the belt contact, not the shaft's weight.)

We need a large contact-patch, not like a bike tire that only touches the road over a few cm:

- A *very* large diameter [as suggested by @John](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253914/best-electricity-generation-from-a-magical-conveyor/253935#253935), like 51 m, so the bottom of the shaft is close to flat over the 10 meter linear distance of the belt which it sits on top of.  (With the belt deforming to wrap around and get a lot of its surface in contact.)
- Or, just under 10 m diameter with the shaft *between* the belt's top and bottom surfaces so it contacts it on both sides.  Total contact should be over more than half of the shaft's circumference, for the full 2m width.  **This requires the rubber to be able to deform a lot, into a nearly round shape.**  But if we're lucky, this can apply huge contact forces on both sides of the shaft without it needing to weigh as much as the great pyramid of Giza.

  We can also stack another shaft on top, so the top side of the belt is basically squished between two rollers.  But the top shaft would have a tiny contact area.  It's still free power, though, and other rollers at angles are possible, especially near the "ends" of the belt where it curves away from our middle shaft to meet the indestructible rollers that are part of the magic belt.

  The contact forces aren't uniform along the contact area: to highest forces are at the top/bottoms, although rollers pressing the belt in could help.  **If the belt can stretch like this, we're increasing its surface area, which would clearly be "cheating" if we insert many different shafts from the side to stretch it around them.**  So this might be disqualified.

To contact a perfectly flat belt that won't deform, we could maybe have a segmented metal belt/tread of flat plates, like tank tracks?  But that would require huge tensile strength of hinges or chain links, and probably have non-constant friction forces so might slip or make the shaft turn in a jerky way, with surges and dips.

Comment: frictional heat will be quite small by generator standards, its moving too slow, you also run into the problem of self lubrication as whatever thing is making the friction breaks and/ softens if you use high pressures to generate more friction.

Comment: @John: Right, it would need immense pressures.  And good point about things softening at such pressures and temperatures, like magma.  So that's probably not viable, unless maybe we can have friction between the belt itself and a solid piece of granite weighed down by more huge pieces of granite, but then you have to get lift lots of mass up high to pile onto it...  Maybe I should move that part of the answer to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Turning relatively low-speed rotation into electricity is exactly what a wind power plant does. We can use all the same principles, merely replacing the rotation powered by wind with rotation powered by the conveyor belt. Simply add some friction-based drive wheels along the belt surface, and gear up the rotation to drive an alternator. You can add as many assemblies as you have room for - since the belt never slows down, it can drive any number of machines. You're only limited by the number of drive wheels, linkages, and gearboxes you can fit.

Off-the-shelf wind turbine gearboxes will get you into the multiple megawatt range very easily, and you can of course optimize from there. You can pack in more gearboxes by making them smaller (but more likely to break), and you can reduce frictional losses inside the machine with more precise machining. There are too many economic and engineering factors to put a number on whether building a particular gear to a tighter tolerance is going to make the machine more profitable or not, or where you hit the exact limit of extra gearboxes' frictional losses canceling the power they produce.

Comment: But the wind has a limited power it can deliver. In this case you could drive something heavier and use different size gears to drive multiple generators at higher speed. Then you need to consider the best materials to touch the conveyor and how to use that to generate more force/torque/whatever than merely a 1:1 conveyor to wind turbine would generate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer does seem to dance around the crux of the question. The power of the belt is essentially limitless, so how far can you take this with your proposed solution? How big will the gearboxes be and how much would it generate? What do you use for contact with the belt?

Comment: @Trioxidane Added some details. You can get to megawatts easily, and from there I expect the sky is the limit. There will be intense research and design around this totally free and unlimited source of energy. I don't think the problem is well-defined enough to say how many linkages and gearboxes we can pack in until they start breaking "too often". You can always add another set of gears.

Comment: What would you say is needed for a more well defined question, should I want to ask that question later?

Answer (score 3):

We are limited by maximal force possible to transfer laterally through 2m x 10m of material which is the maximal surface possible in contact with the conveyor at any moment. This is described by shear yield strength. With high end steel that might be around 1000MPa. Multiplied by area 20m2 gives 20 giganewtons force. Power is force multiplied by speed 15,6 m/s which gives 312 gigawatt.

It is admittedly more like theoretical limit, you will need huge wheel to have the contact area snugly fit to whole 10 meter conveyor. That depends on how stiff the conveyor surface is. You need giganewtons of vertical force anyway that means the wheel should weigh thousands of tons.

Comment: the other big issue is friction, if a stronger material has significantly lower coefficient of friction then you either transfer less energy or risk it switching to sliding friction causing you to transfer even less.

Answer (score 3):

### It is about 3 gigawatt generator about the same of a large nuclear powerplant.

Your biggest limit is friction, so you what as big a contact surface as possible. Ideally you want gearing but assuming you can't add gear to your belt really big wheels are the next best thing is as big a contact surface on the belt is possible.

Ideally you want a wheel at least 51 meters in diameters so 1/16th of the wheels surface is the same as the belt to maximize contact area. But really the bigger the wheel the better, a solid steel wheel as big as you can make is best, then you cut grooves in it and rubber coat it for a rubber to rubber contact surface. Of course you can put a wheel on both sides of the belt so you really want 2 such wheels, one on each side of the belt. the one on the bottom is more of a pain since you need it to push up but some creative use of leverage can manage that.  The idea is to generate as much torque as possible then you gears to step it up to dynamo speeds. This is similar to a wind turbine but you want your own system, wind turbines suffer from limits of material strength due to having to balance weight, but you don't care how big your gear box is, it can be bigger than your wheels even.

Alternatively have your wheel drive something much more robust like a water pump. You then store the water and use as needed, using regular turbines. this has the advantage of getting all the output if you start hitting material limits on your gear box. Of course you should be doing something similar with your dynamo energy since you will not be using all of it all the time. Pumped storage to create load stability. the downside is you need to build a BIG water tank

Your limit is your belt to wheel friction so that also set your maximum theoretical output, one side is rubber and the strongest friction coefficient for that is more rubber. A rubber to rubber contact has a coefficient of friction of 1.15. so lets try a simple bit of math 1.15 times the normal force is your maximum output, the crush strength of steel is 655000000 pascals and really you should be builidng it so this is close as possible to the force on the it. BUT the real issue is the sheer strength of your rubber contact, which is 6205000pascals. So 6205000 times 20 for the surface area times 2 for the second wheel and we have 248200000 newtons.

248200000 newtons times the speed of your belt in meters per second give us the watt output. 248200000 times 15.6 = 3871920000 watts.

**Roughly a 3 gigawatt generator or 1/10th the output of the Three Gorges Dam generators, the largest powerplant on earth.** Of course this is the theoretical maximum, real issues like axle friction will causes losses but no matter what you have for losses it is still a powerful generator.

Comment: Wouldn’t a track touching the belt maximize the surface area instead of just the contact point of the wheel? The track can then use teeth on the other side to engage with any number of gears. Likely the most efficient one would simply engage with a single giant gear and turn it, producing energy by using that turning for a dynamo (or a higher RPM gear by having it engage with a smaller gear). The limit would be how much resistance from the dynamo would break the track (or the friction causing the track to wear down).

Comment: @Demigan a track maximizes the contact but the joints between the tracks is a serious weakness. It reduces the load it can take, and the more robust you make them the more contact surface you lose due to the interior angle of the turn they have to make. The links in a track limit the load it can take, while a wheel can have a huge axle to take a huge torque yet it would only make it stronger. A single gear reduction would be ideal but it just may not be possible do to mechanical stress, there is a limit to what a gear can take before the teeth sheer off.

Comment: you could make the tracks wider than the conveyor. While the touching surface area is still the same the total cm^2 material holding the track together can be arbitrarily large. Only the acceleration of the material would require energy, so adding mass to the belt would actually mean a more consistent speed of the belt speed if it slips as it takes longer to slow down.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Gorges_Dam - *the total electric generating capacity of the Three Gorges Dam is 22,500 MW* (from 32x 700 MW turbines) - That's 22.5 gigawatts, larger than your 3.87 GW.  (3.8 GW is nothing to sneeze at, but it's in a similar range to nuclear power plants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_power_stations#In_service .  None of those have 3.8 GW from one reactor, though, more like 1.5 GW at the upper end.)  A large-diameter wheel for a large contact patch does seem like a good strategy, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes good catch I forgot to convert, I will change it.

Comment: @Demigan wide is not the problem it is the diameter of the hinge pins that is the limiting factor, something as comparatively weak as a tank can rip apart or shear their hinge pins, these forces are several orders of magnitude greater.  And the bigger the pins the less contact surface you have because the tread has to curve inwards around the belt, which means there has to be a gap between the treads. It would not be a bad idea if the belt was not so small.

Comment: I think your rubber fails.  The belt has infinite friction, the friction of the coupling is purely a matter of how much downward pressure you can apply.

Comment: @John as I explained, you can make it bigger than the track that powers it, which distributed the sheering force over a larger pin surface area. You also don’t need the track flexibility of a tank, you could put a circular track the size of a dam or bigger on top of the conveyor. Giving you stronger pins.

Comment: @Demigan the total surface of the pin is not the issue it is the cross-sectional diameter, the pin needs to withstand sheering force. the bigger you make the track the more the need to bend inward forces a larger and larger gap between the treads making the contact surface smaller and smaller. the track needs to be fairly flexible to fit the belt. if you are not fitting to the belt the benefit of a track is lost so just use a much much  stronger and simpler wheel.

Comment: @john the pin needs to withstand sheering force with cross section, but it matters if that sheering force is distributed over a 1cm long pin or a 1m long pin, longer means less sheering force per cross sectional area. And as already mentioned you can use a less flexible track by making the bend per meter smaller, making for a bigger circle. Of course at the bottom of the circle it’s flat for a section where it touches the conveyor belt.

Comment: @Demigan that's not how shearing force works, the area the shearing force is spread across is not controlled by the length of the pin but how big the gap is between the two sections of tread the pin is spanning. how well supported the rest of the pin is is irrelevant. And as I said if your track is not wrapping around the belt it losses the one advantage it has while adding a tremendous amount of structural weakness.

Comment: @John it’s literally a formula when you calculate it for a bar: Tau = F/A *per section of bar*. Since the Force can be divided over more sections of bar by making it longer and adding more links where the sheering force happens (which also reduces local bending) you absolutely can divide the shearing forces across a length.

Comment: @Demigan I see what you mean. by having more connections to the same joint, but that runs into the opposite problem, the force can only be spread horizontally a short distance before bending force is greater than the original shearing force. which again is very limited by the pin diameter.  but again what advantage does the track have it is not fitted to the belt?

Comment: @john I’m not sure what you mean with “not fitted to the belt”? If all you do is sheathe the conveyor with a track that goes around then you moved the problem of engagement to the dynamo to another place? Why can’t you run one track along the top and one along bottom of the conveyor, with dynamo’s as sprockets to keep it engaged and the track runs a wide wiiiide circle so it does not need to be as flexible (and can be stronger) and each spot where it turns it engages with a dynamo?

Comment: @Demigan wrapping the track around the belt maximizes the contact surface which is the one advantage a track has over say a large solid wheel or pair of large solid wheels, which minimizes moving parts and maximizes strength of parts. as for why fewer dynamo a smaller number of dynamos is better just do to loses of the dynamo itself, 2 dynamo producing 1 MW each need more input energy than one 2mw dynamo.

Answer (score 2):

The fact is you've designed a perpetual motion machine. Not just *any* perpetual motion machine, but one that can't be stopped: you've designed an unstoppable force. Such things are highly unphysical, since that implies an infinite reservoir of energy to draw from in order to continually overcome whatever forces are placed against the conveyor belt. Which, of course, doesn't exist.

But what if it did?

The fact that it's a conveyor belt is actually not even that important. A conveyor belt is, fundamentally, two wheels spinning in the same direction with a belt between them. So, **you have two unstoppably-spinning wheels, so just hook them up to a huge generator and watch the power pour out.** Nuclear reactors, hydroelectric dams, and wind turbines all operate on the principle that, using some applied electromagnetism, rotation can be converted directly into electricity. None of these things actually "extract electricity" or "power" from the source of energy (i.e. nuclear fuel, falling water, or wind turbines). They just convert one form of energy into another: in a nuclear reactor, the heat from the reactor core produces motion in a liquid or gas that flows past a turbine to spin it; in a hydroelectric dam, the falling water hits a turbine and spins it; and in a wind turbine, wind flowing past a turbine causes it to spin.

It's all in the spin: all of these generators operate on the principle (namely, [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction)) that motion, usually rotation, can be converted into power. But you already have a source of infinite rotation that under no circumstances will stop; so why not just connect one (or, heck, both) of the conveyor belt's wheels to generators as large as possible? The only restriction on how much power you'll be able to generate is what kind of materials you have on hand; if you make the generator's Faraday's disk-like flywheel too big, the speed at which it rotates will pull it apart. But beyond that, you can attach as many flywheels as you want to a central axle, so you can functionally have as much power as you want (barring adding so many flywheels that the generator collapses into a black hole).

Comment: *just hook them up to a huge generator* - Yes, the question is how to do that, given the low speed of the belt and thus extremely large forces required to extract maximum work.

Comment: If the belt is unstoppable, this implies an *infinite* force potential. Unless "unstoppable" means something very different from what I believe it means, I should be able to apply an arbitrarily-large force to the belt, and in response the belt should exert an equally-massive force in the opposite direction. Regardless of how much work you're getting out of the belt, you have infinite power available to you.

Comment: Yes, poor phrasing on my part to say "maximum work".  The maximum depends on the strength of materials that we put in contact with the belt, as in the upper bound from [@Josh King's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/253914/best-electricity-generation-from-a-magical-conveyor/253926#253926) with the shear strength of steel or titanium.

Comment: Yes, that does add an upper limit to the obtainable energy.  I noted that in my answer I believe; I didn't go too far into detail due to lack of details about available materials in the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I got this right.

If...

> What would be the best method to generate electricity in a day?

...means "**How to make this conveyor into powerplant that generates the most energy per day**" then...

You can literally hook the most powerful generator to this contraption. Unit used in Olkiluoto 3 nuclear plant generates over 1700 MW.

To get to its operational 1500 rpm (it is in Europe, so you need 50hz) you need to affix a wheel with diameter of around 20 centimeter (or around 16 cm for USs 60hz) directly to a generator axle.

The wheel needs to be made of material that can apply enough friction so it won't slip while exerting over 2443 kilograms worth of pressure towards the conveyor.

Theoretically you can fit at least one on every side of the conveyor without need for complicated transmission.

...**But if it that means that you need to start generating electricity as quickly as you can, ideally before the next morning.**

Then best solution is to buy as many "home wind turbine DIY kits" as you can fit side-by-side next to your conveyor (if we wish to reduce transmission complexity). i.e. newer Automaxx model can generate 1500W (based on advertising) it operates up to 1400rpm which gives 21 centimeter wheels on axles (which I believe is more than generator width). If I did my math right that is 47 units per side x4 means (left upper belt, right upper, left lower,right lower). thats almost 30 KW in very stable setup that is (almost) DIY level of complexity (plus some very deadly amperage)

Comment: *"You need to affix a wheel with diameter of around 20 centimeter (or around 16 cm for USs 60hz) directly to a generator axle":* Knowing that gears exist, why would a 20 cm wheel be any better than a 10 cm wheel? I ask this because obviously one can fit twice as many 10 cm wheels than 20 cm wheels over the same length of transmission belt.